# About java RMI. How to use LocateRegistry to getRegistry in a remote host with specified port?

Tags: java, rmi

I'm studying java RMI. It's OK to register a Registry in localhost. But how can I register a Registry in a remote host with specified port?

It's OK to execute this code like

```
    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(6600);
    // Register communication route
    Naming.rebind("rmi://0.0.0.0:6600/PersonService", personService);
```

But not like

```
    LocateRegistry.getRegistry("202.114.70.31", 6600);
    // Register communication route
    Naming.rebind("rmi://202.114.70.31:6600/PersonService", personService);
```

Otherwise a `ConnectionException` will be thrown.

Comment: ConnectionException is not thrown because it can't be done, there is some other issue. It is perfectly valid to LocateRegistry from a remote host as shown in the second example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I register a Registry in a remote host with specified port?

You can't. You can only start a Registry in the localhost.

> It's OK to execute this code like

```
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(6600);
// Register communication route
Naming.rebind("rmi://0.0.0.0:6600/PersonService", personService);
```

It's not OK. You can't connect to `0.0.0.0`. It should be `"localhost"`.

> But not like

```
LocateRegistry.getRegistry("202.114.70.31", 6600);
```

Now that *is* OK. *But*, `LocateRegistry.getRegistry()` doesn't *create* a Registry. It gives you a stub to an *existing* Registry, or to nothing if that Registry doesn't actually exist. And note that the call won't fail if it doesn't, but *using* that stub will fail if it doesn't.

```
Naming.rebind("rmi://202.114.70.31:6600/PersonService", personService);
```

And this is not OK. You can only bind/rebind/unbind to a Registry running in the localhost. See the Javadoc.

> Otherwise a `ConnectionException` will be thrown.

No, a `java.rmi.ConnectException` is thrown, and by the `rebind()`, not by the `getRegistry().`